# Drop up for tags input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I want to implement tags input in my reactjs application. I am using "react-select" right now. I want suggestions to open in upward direction instead of dropdown. I have search a lot to find something but couldn't get it. Does someone know of any plugin or library which does that.

this is the current thing I am doing. But it is drop down.

```
import Select from 'react-select';

 <form role="form" className="select-user sselect-type m-l-20 process-react-select">
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <label className="">Assign to</label>
                                            <Select
                                                className="my-cool-select-top"
                                                name="form-field-name"
                                                value={this.state.assignValue}
                                                options={options}
                                                onChange={this.logChange.bind(this)}
                                            />
                                        </div>
```

Comment: If I undertand you correctly, giving these (ugly) properties, might help you: `.Select-menu-outer {
    position: absolute;
    top: -180px;
}`
The key is, you want to change the `Select-menu-outer` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who is using react-select, here is the solution

Add this in your css

```
 div.ReactTags__suggestions{
  top:auto !important
  bottom:100% !important

}
```

This will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the [vertical-align](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp%5C) css rule:

```
.sselect-type { vertical-align: top; }
```

Make sure the rule is applied to your tag and if it does not work, try not to put the tag to the top of the page.